# returning a custom error with Suave, in F#

Tags: f#, suave

Where can I find, in the Suave docs, the way to return an http error with a message as a plain text error?

I keep looking and I just can't find my way through the docs since it's structured as bits of examples here and there.

What I would like to do is this:

```
if thingsGoWell then
    OK myResult
else
    ERROR someHttpStatusCode myString
```

I know I can use the presets, like

```
INTERNAL_ERROR "hello"
```

but I want to be able to pass my own HttpStatusCode.

I'm just beginning to use Suave, I like the concepts so far but I'm really struggling with the documentation style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the basic `response` function:

```
val response : statusCode:HttpCode -> content:byte [] -> WebPart
```

Documentation is [here](https://suave.io/suave.html#def:val%20Suave.Response.response). Usage is like this:

```
response HTTP_501 (UTF8.bytes message)
```

I agree with you that the Suave documentation isn't great. Personally, I often answer questions like this by simply looking in the source code, which is [here](https://github.com/SuaveIO/suave). I have a local copy that I've cloned and built. It's pretty easy, actually.

As an example, in this case, I searched for "INTERNAL_ERROR", since you gave that as a hint, and found this implementation:

```
let internal_error arr = response HTTP_500 arr
let INTERNAL_ERROR message = internal_error (UTF8.bytes message)
```

From that, I was able to construct an answer to your question, and then googled the relevant documentation as well.

Comment: Looks like I'll be cloning it too and putting it in the project for now so I can browse the code as I go. Thanks!

Comment: That's a good idea, and it also makes it easy to debug into Suave when needed.